# Different styles for inline links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, href

```
        <div class="col-lg-3">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav login-right">
            <li><a href="#" style="padding: 0">Login</a> or <a href="#" style="padding: 0;">create account</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
```

Simple question, how to write class in CSS and how to name it to make different colors for those two links, and also to move inline style in external CSS.

I tried to give normal class to each link and just to call that classes in external CSS file but solution fails.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simple question, how to write class in CSS and how to name it to make different colors for those two links, and also to move inline style in external CSS.

You can use `nth-child` and color both `a` tags differently

`ul.nav li a:nth-child(1){
 color:green;
}`

And

`ul.nav li a:nth-child(2){
 color:blue;
}`

Since both have the same `padding` style you can place it in a common style definition

`ul.nav li a{
 padding:0;
}`

**Important**: make sure the external file which you write this in is placed last in your HTML hierarchy. By CSS prioritisation rule the file placed last in the hierarchy gets the priority.

**Edit**: seems like you have many elements with same structure. In this case it's better to select specific element and using `id` will be our best choice. Add `id` to your `ul` as below

`<ul id="colorMe"  class="nav navbar-nav login-right">`

And change your CSS selectors to

`#colorMe li a:nth-child(1)`

Do similar to other selectors too

Comment: It works but does affect on another links in another ui in another div. I need change colors particular on this two link and not affect on any other.

Comment: works fine, but I still don't know why I can give class name to a tag and give style to that class in css

Comment: @Sasa when you write a style using `id` it has more priority over another style written on that element using a `class` .. Also inline Css takes priority over external file styles.. and lot more :) you gotta spend some time in learning the priorities ...